# How to fix subscript out of bounds error when using strsplit function?

Tags: r, dataframe

[image]

I am running the following code

```
x=as.data.frame(database$RT.Information.Choice.)
RT=matrix(c(rep(0,dim(databaseSubset)[1]*90)), nrow  =dim(databaseSubset)[1] ) #90 is the number of games
for (i in 1:dim(databaseSubset)[1]) {
  x_unlist<-strsplit(as.character(x[i,1]), split = ",")
  y<-strsplit(as.character(x[i,1]), split = ",")[[1]]
  RT[i,]=parse_number(y[1:90])
}
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Error in strsplit(as.character(x[i, 1]), split = ",")[[1]] : 
  subscript out of bounds
```

Although the same code is working for other variables in the data frame which are all structured the same.

Comment: we need some test data to reproduce the problem. out of bounds just means that you want to work on a column that isnt there

Comment: thanks @D.J I added an image to show the data structure, I'm not able to share the entire dataset

Comment: just upload a snippet of it using `dput()`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann thanks, that's really helpful for the future. I've actually fixed this problem, it was an error in the .csv download. Thanks though I really appreciate it :)